# When changing a class Instance variable it is changing the same list variable in all of the class intances. Why? They are all marked as self

Tags: python, variables

very new to python, coding and to overflow. Really trying to get the indents correct here, sorry for any eye sores. Promise I will get it better. The issue I am having is when I create a new class instance they all modify the same list. For example both instances, airplane1, and airplane2 modify the same plane_seats list variable. I have everything marked as self and I have tried creating a new list from the old also as in instance variable but I must be missing something. Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
import functions as fun
    
f = open('airplane_seats_all_open.txt', 'r')
var = f.readlines()
y = [list(word) for word in var]
    
    
class Airplane:
    
    def __init__(self, plane_seats, filename):
        self.plane_seats = plane_seats[:]
        self.filename = filename
        self.new_list = [[]]
    
    def getSeats(self):
        return self.plane_seats
    
    def set_planeSeats(self, row, col):
        self.row = row
        self.col = col
        self.assign_seat(row, col)
    
    def assign_seat(self, row, col):
        """This function assigns an 'X' to an empty seat in the airplane, which are marked as a '.' The airplane_seats_all_open.txt file is then updated as appropriate"""
    
        self.new_list = list(self.plane_seats)
    
        # FIRST CHECK IF OCCUPIED
        if self.new_list[row][col] == 'X':
            print("Seat taken, select another.")
    
        # if not occupied
        # Assigns the selected seat via the row and column with an 'X' for occupied
        self.new_list[row][col] = 'X'
    
        print('seat in row', (row + 1), 'and column', fun.col_mod(col), 'has been assigned.')
        # input('Press Enter to continue to menu')
    
        # Returns to the menu.
        # m.user_menu()
    
    
    
filename = 'airplane_seats.csv'
    
airplane1 = Airplane(y, filename) print(airplane1.getSeats()) 
airplane1.set_planeSeats(0, 1) print(airplane1.getSeats())
    
airplane2 = Airplane(y, filename) print(airplane2.getSeats())
```

Comment: I don't see you modifying `self.plane_seats` anywhere, why would it change from the same `y` variable you initialised it with?

Comment: In this code I used the new_list variable as an in between because I thought that might have been the problem initially. But if i change the new_list back to eh plane_seats I still have the same issue unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is that python has a peculiar way to work with lists (e.g. `y = [list(word) for word in var]`) and they are not copied but referenced. I mean y, airplane1.plane_seats and airplanet2.plane_seats all three point to the same memory where the data is stored so if you modify one you are modifying all three.

[https://www.techiedelight.com/deep-copy-list-python/#:~:text=A%20deep%20copy%20can%20be,deepcopy()%20function.&text=This%20works%20by%20constructing%20a,contain%20a%20reference%20to%20themselves](https://www.techiedelight.com/deep-copy-list-python/#:%7E:text=A%20deep%20copy%20can%20be,deepcopy()%20function.&text=This%20works%20by%20constructing%20a,contain%20a%20reference%20to%20themselves).

Try this:

```
import functions as fun
from copy import deepcopy    
f = open('airplane_seats_all_open.txt', 'r')
var = f.readlines()
y = [list(word) for word in var]
    
    
class Airplane:
    
    def __init__(self, plane_seats, filename):
        self.plane_seats = deepcopy(plane_seats)
        self.filename = filename
        self.new_list = [[]]
    
    def getSeats(self):
        return self.plane_seats
    
    def set_planeSeats(self, row, col):
        self.row = row
        self.col = col
        self.assign_seat(row, col)
    
    def assign_seat(self, row, col):
        """This function assigns an 'X' to an empty seat in the airplane, which are marked as a '.' The airplane_seats_all_open.txt file is then updated as appropriate"""
    
        self.new_list = list(self.plane_seats)
    
        # FIRST CHECK IF OCCUPIED
        if self.new_list[row][col] == 'X':
            print("Seat taken, select another.")
    
        # if not occupied
        # Assigns the selected seat via the row and column with an 'X' for occupied
        self.new_list[row][col] = 'X'
    
        print('seat in row', (row + 1), 'and column', fun.col_mod(col), 'has been assigned.')
        # input('Press Enter to continue to menu')
    
        # Returns to the menu.
        # m.user_menu()
    
    
    
filename = 'airplane_seats.csv'
    
airplane1 = Airplane(y, filename) print(airplane1.getSeats()) 
airplane1.set_planeSeats(0, 1) print(airplane1.getSeats())
    
airplane2 = Airplane(y, filename) print(airplane2.getSeats())
```